# Find all pages in wordpress that contact a certain link

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a apply now button on my wordpress site across a lot of pages, how can i check which pages have the apply now button link without having to check each page manually

Comment: Probably easiest to do, if you search for the relevant code or a portion of it, in the database ...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search the site using the built in WordPress search. If you don't have that active anywhere on the public facing side of your site, just go to your site URL and add ?s=/the-link-you-are-looking-for/ to the end of it.

example:

If you are searching for all instances of http://www.prnewswire.com on the https://www.sonymusic.com/ WordPress site, you could do so like this:

```
https://www.sonymusic.com/?s=http://www.prnewswire.com
```